# How can I open another page when pressing the Edit button on a gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a Gridview control in asp.net with C#.

In my application when I press the edit button from Gridview I need to open the information in another window. At this moment I use 'Response.Redirect("..")' but it opens in the same window.

I've tried:

```
 protected void OutputGridView_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            outputGridView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            GridViewRow row = outputGridView.Rows[outputGridView.EditIndex];
           
            string url = "http://localhost/MyPage.aspx";
            Response.Write("<script>");
            Response.Write("window.open('" + url + "')");
            Response.Write("<" + "/script>")
 
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
```

But with no luck.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will open the window in new window. for this you need to use the ScriptManager

```
string BrowserSettings = "status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,resizable=no,"+
                                        "titlebar=no, addressbar=no, width=600 ,height=750";
            string URL = "http://localhost/MyPage.aspx";
            string scriptText = "window.open('" + URL + "','_blank','" + BrowserSettings + "');";
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "ClientScript1", scriptText, true);
```

Comment: it's working, but how can I modify it to open the page in another tab in stead of another window?

Comment: i think its default browser behaviour .. whether to open in new tab/window

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
protected void OutputGridView_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        outputGridView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        GridViewRow row = outputGridView.Rows[outputGridView.EditIndex];

        string url = "http://localhost/MyPage.aspx";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("<script type='text/javascript'>");
        sb.AppendLine("window.open('" + url + "')");
        sb.AppendLine("<" + "/script>");
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myjs", sb.ToString(), false);
        //or if the gridview is inside an updatepanel do the code given below
        //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1, UpdatePanel1.GetType(), "myjs", sb.ToString(), false);
    }
    catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException)
    {
        throw;
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        //handle error here
        //Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(err);
    }        
}
```

As I have commented in the code above, if you are using ScriptManager, uncomment and use this

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1, UpdatePanel1.GetType(), "myjs", sb.ToString(), false);
```

I have tested it and its working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing directly to the response stream try this:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "OpenNewWindow", "window.open(...)", true);
```

Comment: If you're using Microsoft AJAX then you should use ScriptManager object instead of making calls to the methods of the Page.ClientScript (since they has no effect if the postback is occurred asynchronously).

Answer (score 0):

ASPX: Create a gridview like this

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ID="gvSticker"
                                                        Width="100%" EmptyDataText="No sticker found for this Fisher. Click on add to Add a new sticker."
                                                        HorizontalAlign="Left" ShowFooter="True" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" BackColor="White"
                                                        BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" PageSize="3"
                                                        OnRowDataBound="gvSticker_RowDataBound" OnPageIndexChanging="gvSticker_PageIndexChanging">
                                                        <Columns>
                                                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                                                    <table style="width: 100%">
                                                                        <tr align="left">
                                                                            <td style="width: 15%">
                                                                                Sticker Year
                                                                            </td>
                                                                            <td style="width: 15%">
                                                                                Sticker Number
                                                                            </td>
                                                                            <td style="width: 15%">
                                                                                Issue Date
                                                                            </td>
                                                                            <td style="width: 35%">
                                                                                Issue Type
                                                                            </td>
                                                                            <td style="width: 20%">
                                                                                Status
                                                                            </td>

                                                                        </tr>
                                                                    </table>
                                                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                                    <table style="width: 100%">
                                                                        <tr align="left">
                                                                            <td style="width: 15%">
                                                                                <%# Eval("YearOfIssue")%>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                            <td style="width: 15%">
                                                                                <asp:HyperLink ID="hlStickerNumber" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("StickerNumber")%>' Style="cursor: hand; text-decoration:underline"></asp:HyperLink>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                            <td style="width: 15%">
                                                                                <%# Eval("DateOfIssue", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")%>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                            <td style="width: 35%">
                                                                                <%# Eval("RegistrationType")%>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                            <td style="width: 20%">
                                                                                <asp:Label ID="lblStickerStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StickerStatus")%>'></asp:Label>
                                                                            </td>

                                                                        </tr>
                                                                    </table>
                                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        </Columns>
                                                        <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
                                                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                                        <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                                        <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" ForeColor="#000066" />
                                                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                                                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
                                                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                                                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
                                                        </asp:GridView>
```

In data bound event add the code.

```
 protected void gvSticker_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["FisherId"] != null)
            {
                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    Label lblStatus = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblStickerStatus");


                    if (e.Row.RowIndex == 0)
                    {
                        if (lblStatus.Text.Contains("Active"))
                        {
                            btnAddSticker.Enabled = false;
                            HyperLink hlStickerNum = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("hlStickerNumber");
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hlStickerNum.Text.Trim()))
                            {
```

> string urlWithParameters =
>   "Stickers.aspx?StickerId=" +
>   hlStickerNum.Text;
>                                       hlStickerNum.Attributes.Add("OnClick",
>   "popWinNote('" + urlWithParameters +
>   "')");

```
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            btnAddSticker.Enabled = true;
                            btnVoidSticker.Enabled = true;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                btnAddSticker.Enabled = true;
                btnVoidSticker.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
```

And in aspx page add a function in script tag PopWinNote to open a show modal dialog if you need a small window. This code is not actually your required code but might give you idea regarding the implementation of logic